# Reprogrammable Remote Power Supply Raspberry Pi Monitor and Control

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, raspberry-pi, remote-control

I currently have a reprogrammable power supply (HCS-3400) hooked up to be controlled remotely from an control/monitor app provided by the power supply company, Manson. The supply is connected via USB to a Raspberry Pi B+ which is connected to the internet network (Ethernt), thus can be accessed from the App.

I am looking for a way i can track the voltage, current and power coming from the supply to the Raspberry and hopefully create some code which could stop the Supply from reaching a threshold level/s or from varying abruptly.

Does anyone have any ideas for this? I was thinking either finding some kind of Watchdog software or see if Python on the Pi can control USB input/outputs

HELP

Answer (score 1):

It has a Python sample program for Raspberry Pi on Manson Website which showing how to program HCS in Raspberry Pi using Python.

http://www.manson.com.hk/software

Why you would like track the voltage, current and power coming from the supply to the Raspberry?

Comment: Why indeed. Set it and forget it, right?